# what is error in this C code using realloc?

Tags: c, heap-memory

I am trying to have some kind of dynamically growing array/data structure in C. Below is the C code I have for it. But after it prints the array, it gives a run-time error as shown below in the snapshot. What is going wrong? It is being compiled using MS-Visual C++ 2010 (Free version) on a Windows-7.

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
 int *a;
 int i = 5;

 if((a = (int *)malloc(i * sizeof(int))) == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Error: failed malloc\n");
  return 1;
 }
 for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
  a[i] = i;

 printf("-- array after malloc\n");
 for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
  printf(" a[%d] = %d\n", i, a[i]);

 if((a = (int *)realloc(a, i * sizeof(int))) == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Error: failed realloc\n");
  return 1;
 }
 for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
  a[i] = i;


 printf("\n-- array after realloc\n");
 for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
  printf(" a[%d] = %d\n", i, a[i]);


 free(a);
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//<important> 
//weren't you supposed to do i = 10 here ????
//</important>
if((a = (int *)realloc(a, i * sizeof(int))) == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Error: failed realloc\n");
  return 1;
 }
 for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
  a[i] = i;
```

I think this was supposed to resize array to 10 and use it, but you never changed `i` to `10` so `i` is still `5` and you go out of range

Comment: @nightcracker: `i` is 5, not 4 :)

Comment: @Armen - What does realloc take - the new size or size you want to increase it by?

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
if((a = (int *)realloc(a, i * sizeof(int))) == NULL) {
```

`i` still contains the value `5`. So basically you are `realloc`'ing for 5 integers while you assign 10 integers in the next loop: an error.

This would be the fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
 int *a;
 int i;

 if((a = (int *)malloc(5 * sizeof(int))) == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Error: failed malloc\n");
  return 1;
 }

 for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
  a[i] = i;

 printf("-- array after malloc\n");
 for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
  printf(" a[%d] = %d\n", i, a[i]);

 if((a = (int *)realloc(a, 10 * sizeof(int))) == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Error: failed realloc\n");
  return 1;
 }

 for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
  a[i] = i;

 printf("\n-- array after realloc\n");
 for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
  printf(" a[%d] = %d\n", i, a[i]);


 free(a);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: i is 5 not 4. The previous for loop terminates at 5.

Comment: @Goldenmean: Yeah sorry, I had a little fail moment there.